# Run at command in two minutes time

Tags: at

I'm trying to perform a one-liner using `at`.

Basically, I want to send an SMS at some point in the future.

Here's my command to send an SMS:

```
php -r 'include_once("/home/eamorr/open/open.ie/www/newsite/ajax/constants.php");sendCentralSMS("08574930418","hi");'
```

The above works great! I receive my sms in a couple of seconds.

Now, how can I get `at` to run this command in future?

I tried

```
php -r 'include_once("/home/eamorr/open/open.ie/www/newsite/ajax/constants.php");sendCentralSMS("08574930418","hi");' | at now + 2 minutes
```

But this sends my command immediately! I want to send the message in 2 minutes' time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because that's not how the `at` command works. `at` takes the command in via STDIN. What you're doing above is running the script and giving its output (if there is any) to `at`.

This is the functional equivalent of what you're doing:

```
echo hey | at now + 1 minute
```

Since `echo hey` prints out just the word "hey" the word "hey" is all I'm giving `at` to execute one minute in the future. You probably want to echo the full `php` command to `at` instead of running it yourself. In my example:

```
echo "echo hey" | at now + 1 minute
```

**EDIT:**

As @Gnouc pointed out, you also had a typo  in your at spec. You have to say "now" so it knows what time you're adding 1 minute to.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean. Is there a workaround that you can think of? Thank you,

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Totally confused for a moment there... But I got it to work! Yippee! (Just updating the OP now)

Comment: On CentOS, I had to use at now + 1 minutes 
(plural minutes, not singular minute).

Comment: Any way to specify time in seconds ?

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your syntax:

```
php -r 'include_once("/home/eamorr/open/open.ie/www/newsite/ajax/constants.php");sendCentralSMS("08574930418","hi");' |
at now + 2 minutes
```

From `man at`:

```
You can also give times like now + count time-units, where the time-units 
can be minutes, hours, days, or  weeks and  you  can  tell  at to run the 
job today by suffixing the time with today and to run the job tomorrow by
suffixing the time with tomorrow.
```

You should wrap your php command in a shell script, then execute it.

```
$ cat sms.sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php -r 'include_once("/home/eamorr/open/open.ie/www/newsite/ajax/constants.php");sendCentralSMS("08574930418","hi");'
```

Then:

```
$ at -f sms.sh now + 2 minutes
```

Comment: I really didn't want to have to create a load of files. This thing is going to be called a lot and I don't want file conflicts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just concerned with sending the message after 2 minutes irrespective of the approach, I would suggest using `sleep`.

```
( sleep 120 ;  php -r 'include_once("/home/eamorr/open/open.ie/www/newsite
/ajax/constants.php");sendCentralSMS("08574930418","hi");' )
```

Comment: Maybe. What happens if the server falls over? Do I lose all my notifications? Some are set to weeks/months in advance. Does `at` preserve scheduled tasks on restart?